# How do I split up a navigation bar into two sections in the same line?

Tags: html, css, web, design-patterns, nav

Here's my HTML:

```
<body>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggle" id="js-navbar-toggle">
            <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
        </span>
    <a href="#" class="logo">logo</a>
    <ul class="main-nav" id="js-menu">
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-links">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-links">Products</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-links">About Us</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-links">Contact Us</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-links">Blog</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: "Josefin Sans", sans-serif;
}

.navbar {
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.main-nav {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: none;
}

.nav-links,
.logo {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.main-nav li {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 15px auto;
}

.logo {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 22px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.navbar-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  font-size: 24px;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}
```

And this is the output I'm getting:

[image]

I'd like my output to be like this instead (ignore the spacing difference, just my screenshot, but have them split in the center like so):

[image]

What's the best way of doing this?

I'm thinking of creating another unorder list and moving it, but I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of `justify-content: space-between;`.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.nav-links, .logo {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

.navbar {padding: 20px;}
.navbar, ul {display: flex; flex-direction:row;}
ul li {padding: 0 5px;}
.wrapper {display:flex; justify-content: space-between; width:100%; }
```

```html
  <nav class="navbar">
    <a href="#" class="logo">logo</a>
    <div class="wrapper">
    <ul class="main-nav" id="js-menu">
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-links">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-links">Products</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-links">About Us</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="ul2">
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-links">Contact Us</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-links">Blog</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```